# Load an image from included php not in root directory of server

Tags: php, image, url, load

I'm stuck in a simple thing as loading an image in php.
All included php files are in a directory called includes.
Index.php is in root folder.
When I call img src from the php file located in the root folder, I can see images.
But when I include a section that is supposed to load an image like that:

```
<?php include("includes/section.php"); ?>
```

calling this:

```
<div class = "right">
<h1> news </h1>
<hr>
echo '<img src="../img/do.png" width="200"  alt="Rifrazione news/>';
<p class = "rightp">Blabla </p><br
</div><!--end of right-->
```

I get nothing

Answer (score 2):

for images I prefare use global variable.

Try do something like this:

```
<?
$baseUrl = "http://localhost";   // CHANGE IT TO YOUR URL
?>    
<div class = "right">
<h1> news </h1>
<hr>
<? 
echo '<img src="'.$baseUrl.'/img/do.png" width="200"  alt="Rifrazione news" />'; 
?>
<p class = "rightp">Blabla </p><br />
</div><!--end of right-->
```

Comment: <? $baseUrl = "http://localhost/rifrazione";?> This is my base url retrieved from xamp but the image doens't actually show. In the page I only see these closing symbols tag     '; ?>

Answer (score 1):

The file you're currently in is your current working directory. So find the location of your image from the directory your index.php is in, that means probably removing the `../`. If you have any doubts `echo getcwd();`.

**NEVER** do what Adam suggested. You should always use file system paths, never url paths to local files. **EDIT** *Reasoning:* Hotlinking is part of it as he may not be aware of why something isn't working as it has worked in other locations but mostly due to routing/.htaccess/url rewriting. If he were to move on later to an MVC or similar framework putting localhost/controller/action will not return his image, but he may not be sure why as this is a bad habit he has already picked up. The other reason was for ease-of-use, if he puts a path like ./image/here.jpg opposed to localhost*/here.jpg he may have to go through and rewrite every link if he were to migrate later to an external server.

Example to help visualize better:
If you have the following directory:

```
my_site/
    js/
    css/
    images/
        image.jpg
    index.php
    bob/
        bob.php
        contactBob.php
```

If you were viewing index.php, your link to images would be `/images/image.jpg`.
If you were viewing contactBob.php your link to images would be `../images/image.jpg`.

Comment: Hey Stano, hotlinking is part of it as he may not be aware of why something isn't working as it has worked in other locations but mostly due to routing/.htaccess/url rewriting. If he were to move on later to an MVC or similar framework putting http://localhost/controller/action will not return his image, but he may not be sure why as this is a bad habit he has already picked up. The other reason was for ease-of-use, if he puts a path like ./image/here.jpg opposed to http://localhost/*/here.jpg he may have to go through and rewrite every link if he were to migrate later to an external server.

Comment: If you have an application in which it is necessary to move all the images on an external media server then my solution seems to be the best. You have $baseUrl in the configuration file and only change the value there.

Comment: So what value should be passed to the variable $baseUrl, Sam? I agree to the fact the relative path are better, since you don't have to change them when you move your data to another domain.

Comment: See my comment under your last comment on DevIshOne's answer.

Comment: Edited answer to visualize the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

In [HTML5, you can declare the `<base>` as a DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Comment: This is for making urls relative, should be used for links and not for files on the local system.

Comment: You've got something negative to say about everyone else who answered.. why is that? Always right are ya, Sam? Tone it down or you won't last on SO for very long.

Comment: getcwd gets me to this path C:\xampp\htdocs\Rifrazione but I still can't see the image.

Comment: getcwd() will get the directory the file that is currently executing is in, I listed that there as a tool if you were unsure about where you were when in file x. So getcwd() + your path to image + your image file should produce your image. On linux, a `.` is synonymous with the current directory & this is where the the journey for your image starts.

If your image is in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rifrazione\images\ your image tag should look like `<img src="/images/image.jpg" />`.

Comment: Both yourself and Adam gave a similar answer, 1+1 != 87 no matter who writes it. Regardless, I didn't mean to sound like a dick. But please read my comment to Stano for my reasoning. I'd rather someone learn properly from the start than correct bad habits later.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and testing...it was none of that.
The only thing missing was the php tag at the beginning of the bracket.

You don't need variables at all.
This syntax is working as intended.

```
<?php
echo '<img src="img/do.png" width="120"  alt="Rifrazione news"/>';
?>
```

Thanks for jumping in, anyway.